# How to fix Build.gradle() error in Android Studio when using Jococo as a dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to build an open-source project named AmazeFileManager from Github - [AmazeFileManager](https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager)

I have previously built the project in Android Studio using Gradle with

Android Gradle plugin: **3.6.4**
Gradle version: **5.6.4**

### **Problem:**

When I tried updating the Android plugin and Gradle versions to

Android Gradle Plugin: **4.1.0**
Gradle Version:  **6.5**

I get this error when rebuilding the project:

***Cannot set the value of read-only property 'executionData' for task ':app:jacocoTestFdroidDebugUnitTestReport' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport***

### **Question:**

What can I do to resolve this error so I can successfully rebuild the project?

*Below are the snippets of the  Gradle files  used:*

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "4.3.0"
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = 2
        maxHeapSize = "2g"
        forkEvery = 2
    }
}

spotless {
    java {
        licenseHeaderFile 'spotless.license-java'
        target 'app/src/**/*.java'
        googleJavaFormat('1.7')
        removeUnusedImports() // removes any unused imports
        importOrder 'java', 'javax', 'org', 'com', 'android', 'androidx', ''
    }
}

configurations {
    robo16
    robo17
    robo18
    robo19
    robo21
    robo22
    robo23
    robo24
    robo25
    robo26
    robo27
    robo28
    robo29
}

dependencies {
    robo16 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.1.2_r1-robolectric-r1"
    robo17 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-r1"
    robo18 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.3_r2-robolectric-r1"
    robo19 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.4_r1-robolectric-r2"
    robo21 "org.robolectric:android-all:5.0.2_r3-robolectric-r0"
    robo22 "org.robolectric:android-all:5.1.1_r9-robolectric-r2"
    robo23 "org.robolectric:android-all:6.0.1_r3-robolectric-r1"
    robo24 "org.robolectric:android-all:7.0.0_r1-robolectric-r1"
    robo25 "org.robolectric:android-all:7.1.0_r7-robolectric-r1"
    robo26 "org.robolectric:android-all:8.0.0_r4-robolectric-r1"
    robo27 "org.robolectric:android-all:8.1.0-robolectric-4611349"
    robo28 "org.robolectric:android-all:9-robolectric-4913185-2"
    robo29 "org.robolectric:android-all:10-robolectric-5803371"
}

def robolectricDependencies = "${rootProject.buildDir.path}/robolectric"

task fetchRobolectricDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.robo16
    from configurations.robo17
    from configurations.robo18
    from configurations.robo19
    from configurations.robo21
    from configurations.robo22
    from configurations.robo23
    from configurations.robo24
    from configurations.robo25
    from configurations.robo26
    from configurations.robo27
    from configurations.robo28
    from configurations.robo29
    into robolectricDependencies
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") || project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
            android {
                testOptions.unitTests.all {
                    systemProperty 'robolectric.offline', 'true'
                    systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.dir', robolectricDependencies
                }
            }

            tasks.withType(Test) {
                it.dependsOn fetchRobolectricDependencies
            }
        }
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("jacoco-android")){
            android {
                testOptions.unitTests.all {
                    jacoco {
                        excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'

            if (project.hasProperty('kapt')) {
                kapt 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
                kapt 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
                kapt 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2'
            }

            annotationProcessor 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
            annotationProcessor 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
            annotationProcessor 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2'
        }
    }

}
```

**build.gradle(Project:AmazeFileManager-release-3.5)**

```
   buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
            classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.4'
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "4.3.0"
    }
    
    allprojects {
    
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
            mavenCentral()
        }
        tasks.withType(Test) {
            maxParallelForks = 2
            maxHeapSize = "2g"
            forkEvery = 2
        }
    }
    
    spotless {
        java {
            licenseHeaderFile 'spotless.license-java'
            target 'app/src/**/*.java'
            googleJavaFormat('1.7')
            removeUnusedImports() // removes any unused imports
            importOrder 'java', 'javax', 'org', 'com', 'android', 'androidx', ''
        }
    }
    
    configurations {
        robo16
        robo17
        robo18
        robo19
        robo21
        robo22
        robo23
        robo24
        robo25
        robo26
        robo27
        robo28
        robo29
    }
    
    dependencies {
        robo16 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.1.2_r1-robolectric-r1"
        robo17 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-r1"
        robo18 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.3_r2-robolectric-r1"
        robo19 "org.robolectric:android-all:4.4_r1-robolectric-r2"
        robo21 "org.robolectric:android-all:5.0.2_r3-robolectric-r0"
        robo22 "org.robolectric:android-all:5.1.1_r9-robolectric-r2"
        robo23 "org.robolectric:android-all:6.0.1_r3-robolectric-r1"
        robo24 "org.robolectric:android-all:7.0.0_r1-robolectric-r1"
        robo25 "org.robolectric:android-all:7.1.0_r7-robolectric-r1"
        robo26 "org.robolectric:android-all:8.0.0_r4-robolectric-r1"
        robo27 "org.robolectric:android-all:8.1.0-robolectric-4611349"
        robo28 "org.robolectric:android-all:9-robolectric-4913185-2"
        robo29 "org.robolectric:android-all:10-robolectric-5803371"
    }
    
    def robolectricDependencies = "${rootProject.buildDir.path}/robolectric"
    
    task fetchRobolectricDependencies(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.robo16
        from configurations.robo17
        from configurations.robo18
        from configurations.robo19
        from configurations.robo21
        from configurations.robo22
        from configurations.robo23
        from configurations.robo24
        from configurations.robo25
        from configurations.robo26
        from configurations.robo27
        from configurations.robo28
        from configurations.robo29
        into robolectricDependencies
    }
    
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate {
            if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") || project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
                android {
                    testOptions.unitTests.all {
                        systemProperty 'robolectric.offline', 'true'
                        systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.dir', robolectricDependencies
                    }
                }
    
                tasks.withType(Test) {
                    it.dependsOn fetchRobolectricDependencies
                }
            }
            if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("jacoco-android")){
                android {
                    testOptions.unitTests.all {
                        jacoco {
                            excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dependencies {
                compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'
    
                if (project.hasProperty('kapt')) {
                    kapt 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
                    kapt 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
                    kapt 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2'
                }
    
                annotationProcessor 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
                annotationProcessor 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
                annotationProcessor 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2'
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**build.gradle(Module:commons_compress_7z)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.18'
    implementation 'org.tukaani:xz:1.8'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already found the cause for this, it is because of changes in Gradle 6, which the new AGP uses.

For more info, check out this [Medium post](https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-resolved-jacoco-plugin-error-after-upgrading-gradle-to-6-1-1-d85c0086d66a) or more specifically [this PR](https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin/pull/75) in the `jacoco-android` library that you are using to add the jacoco tasks.